# Configuring Tomcat and non-EE Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, ubuntu

I have the basic (how do I check exactly what I have?) Eclipse version 3.3.

I am trying to get it to remove the squiggly red error lined from my import statements that try to import the servlet libraries like this:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
```

What is the best way to do that?  I think it is just not configured to know where the Tomcat libs are.

I tried to follow this example:
[How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)
but I think my version of Eclipse is pretty different than the example assumes.  I couldn't find the servers view to tell it to use Tomcat.

I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the WTP separately via Eclipse update tool by *Help > Install new Software > Set URL to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios*.

However, I'd warmly recommend to just throw away your non-EE version and download the [*real* Eclipse for Java EE version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1). I've read here and there that upgrading it by the update tool doesn't always yield the desired results.

If your major concern is the loss of preferences/settings, then it's good to know that you can just export/import them by *File > Export/Import > General > Preferences*. Also any existing projects can be re-imported without issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the servlet-api.jar on your build path to remove those errors. But don't just include it inside `WEB-INF/lib` as it'll conflict with your tomcat when it's deployed as a webapp.